# Solr - Analysis works but zero query results

Tags: solr

I'm trying to add support for Chinese in my index by using  `SmartChineseAnalyzer` but despite working as expected in the Analysis page, trying to query does not return the item with the same text.

In the Analysis page, I'm using the following Chinese text as `Field Value (Index)` and **滴灌** as `Field Value (Query)`.

The tokenization and marking of the searched term seem to work as expected (query value marked in bold):

> netafim | 是 | 用于 | 实现 | 可 | 持续 | 未来 | 的 | **滴灌** | 和 | 微 | 灌溉 | 解决 | 
>   | 案 | 的 | 全球 | 领导者 |   | 在 | 水 |   | 粮食 | 安全 | 和 | 耕地 | 的 |
>   交汇 | 处 |   | **滴灌** | 可 | 使 | 种植 | 者 | 以 | 最低 | 的 | 环境 | 影响 | 实现 
>   | 粮食 | 生产 | 的 | 最大化

However, simply querying for **滴灌** in the query page does not return any results.

It's important to note that this text does indeed appear in an item's attribute (`description_zh`) and that I AM able to find the item by querying by the parallel english attribute (`description_en`).

My configuration:

Solr version - 6.4.2

#### schema.xml

```xml
...
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_general_zh" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cn.smart.SmartChineseAnalyzer"/>
</fieldType>

...

<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="description_en" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="description_zh" type="text_general_zh" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="size" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="name_en" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="name_zh" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

...

<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<!-- Copy Fields -->
<copyField source="name_en" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="name_zh" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="description_en" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="description_zh" dest="text"/>

...
```

#### solrconfig.xml

```xml
...

  <luceneMatchVersion>6.4.2</luceneMatchVersion>

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lib" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs" />

  <lib dir="../lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../lib/" regex="lucene-analyzers-smartcn-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />

  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" 
                    class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}">
  </directoryFactory>

  <codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>

  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>


  <dataDir>${solr.blacklight-core.data.dir:}</dataDir>

  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="true" >
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
  </requestDispatcher>

  <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" startup="lazy" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />

  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">  
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst> 
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- config for the admin interface --> 
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

  <requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="defType">dismax</str>
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>

       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>

       <str name="q.op">OR</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>

       <str name="mm">2&lt;-1 5&lt;-2 6&lt;90%</str>

       <str name="qf">
         name^100000
         description^25000
         text
       </str>
       <str name="pf">
         name^1000000
         description^250000
         text^10
       </str>

       <str name="fl">
          id, 
          name_en,
          name_zh,
          size,
          description_en,
          description_zh,
          created_at,
          updated_at
       </str>

       <str name="facet">true</str>
       <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
       <str name="facet.limit">10</str>
       <str name="facet.field">company_size</str>

     </lst>

    ...
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!
Simon.

Comment: Which field are you searching? If you're searching `text`, any analysis performed happens depending on the definition on _that_ field, and not for the fields you're copying from (copying happens before analysis)

Comment: I want to be able to search using the q parameter, which by default indeed uses the `text` field. How do I implement searching with 2 different field types then? I want english search terms to be found in `description_en` using the standard English analyzer and Chinese search terms to be found in `description_zh` using the Chinese analyzer.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Let's look closely at your **solrconfig.xml**:

```
   <str name="qf">
     name^100000
     description^25000
     text
   </str>
```

Which means you have `name`, `description` and `text` as query-fields in your `dismax` query-parser (with different field-boosts, but that's not that important).

(2) The `text` field accumulates field-values from several sources: `name_en`, `name_zh`, `description_en`, `description_zh`. This is what your **schema.xml** is doing:

```
<!-- Copy Fields -->
<copyField source="name_en" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="name_zh" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="description_en" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="description_zh" dest="text"/>
```

(3) From the other side the `text` field doesn't have has analysis for Chinese language (I bet it has `fieldType=text_general` - please correct me if I'm wrong). So by querying against `text` field you will never get Chinese-related text-analysis.

(4) In order to solve your problem you should make separation of the query-time field-set. I.e. instead of `text` field (which is accumulator for all fields) make it separate, like this:

```
   <str name="qf">
     name^100000
     description^25000
     name_en
     name_zh
     description_en
     description_zh
   </str>
```

And then the analyzer will be run against proper `fieldType`:

- `field=description_en` against `fieldType=text_general`
- `field=description_zh` against `fieldType=text_general_zh`

Comment: I ended up copying only english fields to `text_en` and Chinese fields to `text_zh`, then creating 2 separate requestHandlers, with the only difference between them being a different df value (also commented out pf and qf). I then choose which requestHandler to use at the application level. Considering I don't really need different weights for the fields, is this option better/worse?

Comment: It also could resolve your problem :) That's cool if you could separate it on client-side. Sometimes it is good, but sometimes it makes additional coupling with clients. So if you want your requestHandler to be generic you could specify all fields you want to make search against in the `qf` parameter; it also will work.

Comment: I decided to go with your solution.. for now ;) Thanks!